# How do you escape the Riften jail?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Through one deed or another, I have found myself in Riften jail. How I got there is not it important (I stole someone's sweet roll DX). Me, being the master criminal I am, have found myself in many-a-cell, and through cunning wit alone, I have evaded serving an actual sentence. I will not let Riften stop my streak! The worst part of it all, is that taunting shadowmark. The shadowmark is the symbol for a way out, and beside it, on the wall, is an invisible broken shackel. When I activate said shackel, absolutely nothing happens, and the "activate" promt disappears. Tell me, my internet palls; "How do you escape Riften jail?"

Comment: pick the lock and beat all the guards to death with your fists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this but they both start the same way. Pick the lock, sneak behind the guard in the room on the left, get your stuff. Now you can either

1. Sneak out, pick the main door lock, go out
2. Kill the guards, pick the lock, go out

HOWEVER, you may not want to leave this jail so quickly. It has a bug that allows you to easily level up your pickpocket skill to 100.

Comment: Many thanks, people. I'd expected a vast, dungeon-like maze through the ratways, but I'll settle for walking out the front door. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the secret escape route because [it's bugged](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riften_Jail), that link also tells you how to get out but you'll have to get arrested.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a guard walks by, pickpocket him/her for the jail key. When the guard leaves, open the cell door *but leave the jail key in the drawer*. (The guards' keys don't respawn)

Answer (score -1):

Pick up the basket by the table and go to the broken shackle, run and you will go through the wall and be out of jail cell.

Comment: Is this a glitch? being able to run though a wall just because your holding a basket?